# How to "type check" function parameters?

Tags: javascript, typeof

What's the best way to check the type for objects created by Object.create or literal, for example the following code. I want to make sure the arguments to the function is safe to use. Maybe I shouldn't check the type of arguments, but check whether the properties the function uses are not undefined. But it seems very tedious to do so. What's the best approach, thanks.

```
var base = {
    name : "abc"
};

var child = Object.create(base);
do_something = function(o) {
    if (typeof(o) === "base") { // will not work
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, that "type check" on the result of the given `Object.create` will never succeed.

Comment: Now, as far as the question, my preference and recommendation is *don't explicitly type-check* (except, perhaps, to provide emulated overloads) .. but Microsoft does so all over in their ASP.NET code, even to the point of having helper functions that take in the values and set of constraints (which throw the most annoying unhelpful hard-to-trace exceptions) ..

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "type". `typeof` is an opertor that is used to determine a [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8), which is probably unhelpful. Do you really want to know whether an object is an instance of a particular constructor? Given the looseness of ECMAScript types and generic–ness of native methods, it's usually best to not attempt strict type testing for Objects (though it might be suitable for primitive values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` can only return the base type like, object, strirng, number, undefined.

```
typeof o === "object"
```

---

`instanceof` can be used if you are **inheriting from the base class**. Eg here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```
function Base() {
  this.name = "abc";
}
var child = new Base();
var a = child instanceof Base;  //true
```

instance of expects the format `<object> insanceof <function>`

---

You can use `isPrototypeOf()` when inheriting using `Object.create()`

```
var base = {name; "abc"};
var child = Object.create(base);

base.isPrototypeOf(child);
```

More info can be read here: [Mozilla Developer Network: isPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/IsPrototypeOf)

---

To check if there exists an object `o` with the attribute `name` non empty, you can do

```
if(typeof o === "object" && typeof o.name !== "undefined")
```

A shorthand can be used, if `name` will not hold `falsy` values like `0`

```
if(o && o.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code base is a variable not a type, In JavaScript function are treated as classes if you want base type then create a function and initialize it and then use `instanceof` that will give you base.

Try this way using `instanceof`:

```
var base = function(){
    name : "abc"
};

var o = new base();
alert(o instanceof base); // true
```

[Here is JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYeKY/)